# Is it to Recommended to write Insert/Update/Delete Authorization code in same Request class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am writing the below code in Request Class for Validation and Authorization. So the Below code is for add/Update record.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return \Auth::user()->isAdmin();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'UserName' => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:tbluser,UserName,' . 
                                                     \Request::get( 'UserID' ) . ',UserID',
        ];
    }
}
```

**My question is:** Should I write the code to check if the current user is authorized or not to delete the record. For that should I use same Request class that is used for Add/Update or an another class specially for delete authentication? If I use same class then rules() will be executed which are meant for add/update

Comment: Why do you want the delete authorization validation in the authorize method? What is it supposed to do? Validation belongs to the rules method and authorization to the authorize method. You shouldn't mix these two.

Comment: My question is: Should I write the code to check if the current user is authorized or not to delete the record. For that should I use same Request class that is used for Add/Update or an another class specially for delete authentication? If I use same class then rules() will be executed which are meant for add/update

Comment: Are those rules the same?

Comment: Instead of keeping your authorisation code in every custom request class your application requires, you could alternatively apply a middleware to the routes.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {

        switch ($this->method()) {

            // Show single record or multiple records
            case 'GET':
            default:
                return true;
            break;

            // Change a record
            case 'POST':
            case 'PUT':
            case 'PATCH':
            case 'DELETE':
               if(\Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch ($this->method()) {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
                return [];
            break;

            case 'POST':
                return [
                    'UserName' => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:tbluser,UserName'
                ];
            break;
            case 'PUT':
            case 'PATCH':

                return [
                    'UserName' => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:tbluser,UserName,' . 
                                                                         \Request::get( 'UserID' ) . ',UserID',
                ];
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The changes to your code is that in one single request file you can make rules and change the authorization based on what type of method was used. The default and get (to show a user or an index or something like that) does not need permission. For all the other methods (which change a record) the user must be an admin.

Comment: I would use Laravel policies por this

Answer (score 2):

In my Laravel applications `authorize()` request method just returns true. I handle authorization in specific methods of base controller class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function authorizeSameOwner($entity)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->is_admin) {
            return;
        }
        $this->authorize("same-owner", $entity);
    }
}
```

Controller's `authorize()` method is performing actual authorization using abilities defined in `AuthServiceProvider`. This is how it looks in my case:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  GateContract  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

        $gate->define("same-owner", function ($user, $entity) {
            if ($user->is_admin) {
                return true;
            }

            if (method_exists($entity, "getOwnerId")) {
                $ownerId = $entity->getOwnerId();
            } else {
                $ownerId = $entity->owner_id;
            }
            return $user->id === $ownerId;
        });
        $gate->define("same-user", function ($user, $entity) {
            return $user->is_admin || $user->id === $entity->id;
        });
    }
}
```

And here is how the actual resource controller methods look like:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  StayRequest  $request
 * @param  Stay $stay
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(StayRequest $request, Stay $stay)
{
    $this->authorizeSameOwner($stay);

    $stay->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route("stays.index");
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  Stay $stay
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy(Stay $stay)
{
    $this->authorizeSameOwner($stay);

    $stay->delete();

    return redirect()->route("stays.index");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this really depends on what you are really building. If you are making a small app which just have a few restricted areas, then you can easily handle this as you are doing.

However if your restricted area is big, I think you should make use of Laravel Policies which will offer much more control and stay much more organized in their own classes.

About how you should split your Request classes I think a class for any request verb is totally fine. Its very common you can use `CreateUserRequest` for create and update, however deletion may have different rules as checking the record really exists or checking your deletion validation checkbox is checked... Just create a different class for its rules.

If you think some of these actions can be authorized by the same rule (`isAdmin` in this case), you can also create an abstract AdminRequest which will handle this authorization. Again, if system is not complex at all.

Comment: So far my application has simple `Request` class that is being used in the `Controller`. So are you in favor of creating two `Request` classes for Insert/Update and Delete respectively?

Comment: Yes I am. I would also create three classes if create and update are not identical.

Comment: Why would you need request for delete action if there is no request? It's just an action URL. You just need to authorize it and that's it.

Comment: You may check things like the record really exists, validate some deletion confirmation... Whatever.